# How to mouse hover then need to click on the tab- Selenium2

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]
Working on selenium webdriver First i want the mouse need to hover to tab which is shown in image. from **Age** to **Time to Resolve**. Using **Java**.

```
if(existsElement("ext-pr-backlog-evolution")==true){
WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.id("ext-pr-backlog-evolution"));// Problem in this line
actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).perform();//
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;// This is exactly opening the page
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.id("ext-pr-backlog-evolution") ));// This is exactly opening the page
Thread.sleep(6000);
}
else{
System.out.println("element not present -- so it entered the else loop");
}
```

Here is the HTML tag

```
<a id="ext-pr-backlog-evolution" class=" ext-pr-backlog-evolution" name="ext-pr-backlog-evolution" href="https://10.4.16.159/extranet_prbacklogevolutiontendency/reports/type/default/">Overview & Evolution</a>
```

In the Image upto **Problem Reports(PR)** the mouse is hovering when trying to click on **Overview and Evloution** tab it is moving to **Ticket** tab but the **Overview and Evloution** page is opening. Exactly it is opening the tab but not hovering and clicking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct page is opening because, you are using javascript to click, which can perform click even for not-displayed elements.
Try to click from your action builder.

```
WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Overview & Evolution"));
actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).click().perform();
```

Dont forget to comment your javascript click.

Comment: I tried with your code.. The problem is it is hovering **Ticket** tab which is present above **Problem Reports** and opening the **Average Time to Assign** tab. I don't know how this is happening. I comment the Javascript before start run your code.

Comment: Is there any other way to fix this issue. Using JavaScript executor i can properly find the element. but at the same time it need to mouse hover then it need to click the tab. Please anyone help me to dix

Comment: For exact mouse over then click, you will have to use "actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).click().perform();". Try what **Amith** has suggested. Use different locator, like linktext. You can also pass element to be clicked in click funtion.

Comment: It is showing error as follows  **Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"ext-pr-backlog-evolution"}
Command duration or timeout: 359 milliseconds** for the above method

Comment: You are using incorrect locator, linktext is the actual text of link. Use the edited code above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried finding element by `linkText`, I know using `id` is the best way to locate elements but trying with different selectors might help you get closer to the problem..

```
WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Overview & Evolution"));
```